# included class from header file does not specify class

Tags: c++

***All other questions on this website do not fix my issue***

I have a file `pid.h`, where I am declaring the `pid` class. In `pid.cpp`, I am defining the function inside the pid class. In my `main.cpp` file, when I include the `pid.h` file, nothing happens. It is also okay when I say `pid myPID;`. But then when I say `myPID.calculate_pid();`, it gives me an error:

`error: 'yPID' does not name a type`

`pid.h`:

```
#pragma once
class pid{
    private:
        float cumError;
        float lastError;
    public:
      float calculate_pid(float setpoint, float currentAngle, float kp, float ki, float kd, float currentTime, float elapsedTime);
};
```

`pid.cpp`:

```
#include "pid.h"

float pid::calculate_pid(float setpoint, float currentAngle, float kp, float ki, float kd, float currentTime, float elapsedTime){
    float error = setpoint-currentAngle;
    // P part of PID
    float pidP = kp*error;
    // I part of the PID
    cumError+=error*elapsedTime;
    float pidI = cumError*ki;
    //D part of PID
    float rateError = (error-lastError)/elapsedTime;
    float pidD = kd*rateError;
    // Output
    float pid_output = pidP + pidI + pidD;
    lastError = error;
    return pid_output;
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "pid.h"
int main() { 
pid myPID;
myPID.calculate_pid();
 }
```

Comment: `myPID.calculate_pid();` should be inside a function.

Comment: @MikeCAT what do you mean?

Comment: In C++ code goes inside functions.

Comment: "All other questions on this website do not fix my issue"  This should be true of every (well-asked) question on this site; so, there should be no need to say it explicitly, especially in bold.

Comment: on my machine your code compiles and apparently works as intended. altho i put the variable definition and method call inside the `main()` and also i have provided the method call with parameters.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66003529/why-there-is-always-main-function-in-c

Comment: With the editted code I'm now guessing some stray characters between the `m` and `y` of `myPID`.

Comment: WFM: https://www.online-cpp.com/c1by5YJM9P

Comment: There is also the lack of parameters to the method `calculate_pid` but it's not clear how that would cause the error given.

Comment: The message looks like `myPID.calculate_pid();` is not your actual code.

Comment: BTW, I notice you're using the PID to control angles. Circles are funny things, the error between 0° and 355° is most probably not 355° but -5°. Your code does not handle this case. You open your PID to a lot more applications if you let the user calculate and pass in the *error* instead of *setpoint* and *actual*.

Comment: @Friedrich make an answer for this. This is interesting.

Comment: @KirillMcQuillin etiquette on this site is an answer is an answer to a question. Your question was how to fix your error, you got an answer. Suggesting changes to your interface or other improvements - however interesting - would not answer your question. Having said that, I think your class should have `kp`, `ki` and `kd` as members (they rarely change), as well as `lastTime` (updated whenever you calculate) and your method should look like this: `float calculate_pid(float error, float currentTime)`. Finally, `error` should be between [-pi, pi] or [-180, 180].

Comment: @KirillMcQuillin Why your error has `yPID`  instead of `myPID`? is there any typo?

Answer (score 0):

First use a main function

```
#include "pid.h"
int main() {
    pid myPID;
    myPID.calculate_pid();
}
```

Second you should add your `pid.cpp` Into your `cmake` command. So They compile together!

```
add_executable(YourProjectName main.cpp pid.cpp)
```